# JDialog with Image Editor

Tags: java, swing, graphics, graphics2d, jdialog

I need to make a little ImageEditor fitted into the JDialog. And it must be executed on

```
int k = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, p,  t, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, 
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, new Object[]{ok, cancel}, ok);
```

creation of the panel:

```
case TEXEDIT:
            panel = new IPanel();
            p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 480));
            panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(780, 440));
            break;
```

its class:

```
static class IPanel extends JPanel {
    BufferedImage image;

    public IPanel() {
        super();
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("res/shipRubeoAles.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

    float scale = 2.0f;
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g; 
        int w = getWidth();  
        int h = getHeight();  
        int imageWidth = image.getWidth();  
        int imageHeight = image.getHeight();  
        double x = (w - scale * imageWidth)/2;  
        double y = (h - scale * imageHeight)/2;
        AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x,y);  
        at.scale(scale, scale);  
        g2.drawRenderedImage(image, at);    
    }

}
```

It should be an "image selector (cropper)", I want to make that object's drawing rectangle (on the spritesheet) will be defined there.

I'd like to stop all the other application activity, while the image editor is opened. 
But there comes some problems, I would not want to stop listening mouse, keyboard events or repainting my panel (which definently stops, **because my panel is not repainted at all, it doesn't even paints the image for the first time, so the panel is totally blank**) inside JDialog, so how to do that JDialog will listen to these event?

Comment: So apart from not calling super.paintComponent, it looks okay. Components placed on the dialog will still receive event notification. Try setting the image x/y to 0x0 and see if it makes a difference

Comment: No, even drawing a simple image doesn't lead to anything

Comment: Lol my bad. Didn't add it to the jdialog with add(component)...

Comment: If you're using JOptinPane, you shouldn't have to, as it will be added automatically. You could do a quick test and change the background color of the panel

Comment: I solved my problem already. Anyway, thanks

Comment: Yes'm but have you found the correct solution or a hack that will sot working in ten minutes...if you've solved the problem and don't want any more correspondence, delete the question